# How to remove duplicate comma separated values from variable using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Want to remove the duplicate values from **machines** variable in below batch file:

```
@echo off
set machines=node1,node2,node3,node2,node4,node1,node7,node6,node4
```

Expected output:

```
node1,node2,node3,node4,node6,node7
```

Comment: Fine, then go for it. Come back here when you are stuck, asking a specific question and providing a [mcve]. Read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` `set "_list="` `for %%? in (%machines%) do set "_l="&(for %%$ in (!_list!) do if "%%~$"=="%%~?" set "_l=1") & if not defined _l if defined _list (set "_list=!_list!,%%?") else set "_list=%%?"` `echo %_list%`

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish your task:

- Iterate the machines with a `for` and set them to an array,
  this overwrites doublette entries.
- Read the (alpha sorted) array back and store in the original variable (requires delayed expansion).

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\09\20\SO_52417320.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set machines=node1,node2,node3,node2,node4,node1,node7,node6,node4

:: clear array machine[], then fill it
For /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%M in ('Set machine[ 2^>Nul') do Set "%%M="
For %%M in (%machines%) do Set "machine[%%M]=%%M"
Set machine[
Echo:    
Set "machines="
For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%M in ('Set machine[') do Set "machines=!machines!,%%M"

Echo:%machines:~1%
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_52417320.cmd
machine[node1]=node1
machine[node2]=node2
machine[node3]=node3
machine[node4]=node4
machine[node6]=node6
machine[node7]=node7

node1,node2,node3,node4,node6,node7
```

Answer (score 0):

A short way to do it (this doesn't sort the **machines** variable, only removes the duplicates):

```
@echo off& setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set machines=node1,node2,node3,node2,node4,node1,node7,node6,node4

set "tmac=,"& for %%a in (%machines%) do if "!tmac:,%%a,=!"=="!tmac!" set "tmac=!tmac!%%a,"
set machines=%tmac:~1,-1%
```